# How to avoid scrolling a UITableView when adding new events?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`. It loads sets of events at regular time intervals. I want to be able to scrol the table view to see all events. I had inserted latest events at position number zero in a row. So whenever I reload the data, my table view has moved one row down. So the user can't view exactly what he wants to read. So I want to reload the `UITableView` without moving its scrolling position. How can I do that?

Note that my event text height should be vary based on events.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use UITableView's [`-scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a) or, probably better, UIScrollView's [`-setContentOffset:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a), to reposition the table view. You'll probably just have to note the current offset, calculate the new offset (based on where & how many rows you added), and set it after you update the table.